# alert() doesn't show the value in a Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, alert, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a Tampermonkey script to unhide one DIV defined like that

```
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
```

My script doesn't work and I don't know why...

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name            Actualisation Vérification Infra 
// @namespace       http://use.i.E.your.homepage/ 
// @version         0.1 
// @description     Permet de recharger la page toutes les x millisecondes afin de garder la session active 
// @match           https://reportingogd.truc.fr/reporting/afficherSynthese.do* 
// @copyright       2013+, The PCU Team 
// ==/UserScript== 

var extern = document.getElementById('div2').style.display; 
alert('extern'); 

// Refresh toutes les xx minutes  
var delay = "30m"; // Remplacer par le temps souhaité, 1s, 10s, 60s, 1m, 15m, 30m, 1h, 3h, ... 

var t = parseInt(delay.match(/\d+/)[0], 10), 
        unit = "", 
        d = 0; 
switch(delay.match(/[ms]/i)[0]) { 
        case "s": 
                unit = "secondes"; 
                d = t * 1000; 
                break; 
        case "m": 
                unit = "minutes"; 
                d = t * 60000; 
                break; 
        case "h": 
                unit = "heures"; 
                d = t * 3600000; 
                break; 
} 

setInterval("window.location.reload()", d); 

alert("Vous n'aviez pas activé la page depuis " + t + " " + unit);
```

when i want show the var "extern", the pop-up give my "extern" and not the value of the DIV...

Please could you help me ?

Ps : The second part of my code work properly, it's a refresh of the web page

Comment: Take out the quotes around `extern` in the alert. `alert(extern)` else it alerts a string

Answer (score 4):

Your alert alerts 'extern' because you alert it as a string.

`alert(extern)` will alert the good value.

And to make the div visible, just:

`document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';`